# How to restore account for Stackoverflow when google account access disabled?

Tags: support

Before a day I had account where I log in with Google credentials.  I used my old company email: `abc@wefi.com`. Company decided to close that gmail so today the account status is `Account access temporarily disabled`.

The problem is that I can't login to stackoverflow account with Google API (aka `abc@wefi.com`). I know user and password.

How can I restore this account?

The only one way is to drive to company IT and ask them to open gmail back for several minutes and try to edit this account by changing email or set `OpenID`.

Is there any other way?

Thank you

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704

Comment: @psubsee2003 how does it help me. I can't login to edit my account.

Comment: Sorry - forgot they didn't have that step in there.  The last step if to simply [contact the SE](http://stackoverflow.com/contact).  They will try to help you out as best as they can.